# PassportJs isAuthenticated not Authenticating

Tags: node.js, express, session, authentication, passport.js

I have **PassportJS** setup with **Google+ Login**.

The Google authentication seems to work fine but when I redirect to a page that only an authenticated user should have access to. Passport's `isAuthenticated()` function always seems to return `false`

I've seen people mention that you should be able to find the user by console logging: `req.session.passport.user` but when I console log `req.session` all I get is:

```
  sessionID: 'Q5NaeyfnAphOK633tKjiGnbbex0KJj7e',
  session:
   Session {
     cookie:
      { path: '/',
        _expires: null,
        originalMaxAge: null,
        httpOnly: true } },
```

**Google Callback route:**

```
router.get("/google/callback", function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate("google", function(err, user, info) {
        req.session.save(()=>{
            res.redirect("/api/v1/dashboard");
            console.log("after Passport AUTH");
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

Note: I've added a manual `req.session.save()` to ensure that the session is being saved.

**Dashboard route:**

```
router.get("/", middleware.isLoggedIn , function(req, res) {
    console.log("Request: Get All Dashboard Data!");
    models.PortfolioBalance.findAll({ raw: true }).then(function(
        portfolioBalance
    ) {
        res.render("dashboard/index", { portfoliobalances: portfolioBalance });
    });
});
```

**Middleware module:**

```
module.exports = {
    isLoggedIn: function(req, res, next) {
        console.log("===========================================");
        console.log("isAuthenticated: ", req.isAuthenticated);
        console.log("===========================================");
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            return next();
        }
        console.log("not authenticated");
        res.redirect("/login");
    }
};
```

**Serialise and De-Serialise:**

```
//  used to serialize the user for the session
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log("SerializeUser:", models.User.userId);
    done(null, user.id);
});

// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    console.log("deserializeUser:", models.User.userId);
    models.User.findOne({ where: { userId: id } }).then(function(
        err,
        user
    ) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

**Potential Issue:**

- Could it be an issue with passportJS not serialising and deserialising properly? Why? because I never see the `console.log` messages being run at any point during the authentication process.

Answer (score 5):

First, you will want to use the authenticate as middleware to protect routes and login.

```
// put in a separate file and then import where you need it for this example lets say auth.js
module.exports = function (){
    return {
        authenticate: passport.authenticate('google', function (err,user){
            if(err)
                res.redirect('/login');
            if(user)
                res.redirect("/api/v1/dashboard");
        })(req,res);
    }
};
```

Like if you login you might set it up as so

```
// where you have your routing
var auth = require('path_to_auth.js')();

router.post('/login', auth.authenticate);
```

Inside of the google strategy is where you want to search for the user.

```
// from the passport-google npmjs.com documentation adjust for the actual strategy you use
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    returnURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google/return',
    realm: 'http://localhost:3000/'
  },
  function(identifier, done) {
    User.findByOpenID({ openId: identifier }, function (err, user) {
      return done(err, user);
    });
  }
));
```

You should also import the user model then serialize and deserialize like so

```
var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema); // adjust to your schema

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```